# class from provider not loading in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel

I want to use a service provider for the Google Geocoding API, https://github.com/jotafurtado/geocode in my Laravel 5.5 application. I followed the instructions, installed the provider using Composer. I had to manually add this line to the providers array in the config/app.php:

```
Jcf\Geocode\GeocodeServiceProvider::class
```

and then add this to the aliases array in the same file

```
'Geocode' => Jcf\Geocode\Facades\Geocode::class
```

When I call the Geocode class in my controller I get an error saying "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Geocode' not found". Is there something I need to add to the controller or some command I need to run?

Comment: If you're using 5.5 then you shouldn't need to manually set the alias or register the service provider since you should be using package auto-discovery

Comment: For some reason auto discovery wasn't working. I think it might have been because my version of composer was out of date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you use an import statement at the top of your controller?

```
use Jcf\Geocode\Facades\Geocode;
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. I don't know why that wasn't included in the provider's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You should use alias name to import the class like

```
use Geocode;
```

Laravel will resolve it for you by using alias name. That is the purpose of creating alias.